# .NET MAUI flyout as a regular sidebar

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

By default .NET MAUI shows its flyout as a hamburger menu. Is there a way to show it as a regular sidebar that is always open and doesn't overlap the content?

Comment: Won't happen on Android/iOS unless you create your own. Also it kind off defeats the purpose of "Flyout"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows you can say

```
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
```

I don't know what that does on mobile, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following code into your `AppShell.xaml` and it will work.

```
<Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">   
                <Setter Property="Shell.FlyoutBehavior" Value="Locked"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shell.FlyoutWidth" Value="55"></Setter>              
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Here is the sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Slapout answer is wright , see the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior

```
Locked – indicates that the flyout can't be closed by the user, and that it doesn't overlap content.
```

Set it in your AppShell.xaml

```
  Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
```